# How do i run a wasm function from with Go language code?

Tags: go, webassembly

I want to run a webassembly module from within a go language code.
I have golang installed, and wasmer installed as well.
From within VSCode terminal- when i execute the version commands for GoLang and wasmer, following is the response.

```
go version go1.20.5 windows/amd64
wasmer 4.0.0
```

When trying to run the following program, it doesn't compile - mentioning

```
undefined: wasmer.NewEngine compilerUndeclaredImportedName
```

similar undefined exceptions for all the wasmer function calls mentioned below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    wasmer "github.com/wasmerio/wasmer-go/wasmer"
)
func main() {
    wasmBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("simple.wasm")

    engine := wasmer.NewEngine()
    store := wasmer.NewStore(engine)

    // Compiles the module
    module, _ := wasmer.NewModule(store, wasmBytes)

    // Instantiates the module
    importObject := wasmer.NewImportObject()
    instance, _ := wasmer.NewInstance(module, importObject)

    // Gets the `sum` exported function from the WebAssembly instance.
    sum, _ := instance.Exports.GetFunction("sum")

    // Calls that exported function with Go standard values. The WebAssembly
    // types are inferred and values are casted automatically.
    result, _ := sum(5, 37)

    fmt.Println(result) // 42!
}
```

Can you please let me know why is this compilation issue happening?

I tried checking if there's any other starter tutorial for the same, most of those point to this standard template program to run. But for me, it is resulting in compilation exceptions.

Comment: There may be missing imports. Can you also post the code from the wasm module? Or at least something that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi @TachyonicBytes, the thing is the code didn't even compile, so the wasm module is inconsequential. 
Question is to run this code, is there anything else which needs to be done 
1. Installed wasmer 
2. Installed golang
From the https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer-go, i followed the instructions, and running it in Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor>
Just wondering if there's any reason for the API to not compile, now when i check the above mentioned doc, it says windows support is in waiting.

Comment: wasmer is unsupported on windows as of yet, see their github repo.

Comment: thank you @nigel239, yes looks like it is not supported on windows.